# How to pass a property to a component via the reactjs router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a reactjs router v2.8.1 in my app and trying to figure out how to pass properties to a component. This is what one of the routes looks like:

```
<Route path="/comp2" component={Component2} />
```

Suppose I am trying to go from Component1 to Component2 and want to pass properties from Component1 what would be a way to do this?

Comment: See if this helps - https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MemoryRouter or NativeRouter, you can send arbitrary state as explained [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/native/api/Link/to-object).

For web though, you should prefer taking dynamic data as either [query params](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location), or [url parameters](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params), as depicted in the links. The reason being that these are stored right within the address. This allows some more browser scenarios (e.g. bookmarks, in-private mode) to work as expected.